# Using Shared Case Class Structure to Make New Case Class Instance

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Suppose I have defined the following case classes:

```
scala> case class A(v1: Int, v2: String)
defined class A

scala> case class B(v1: Int, v2: String, v3: Double)
defined class B
```

Note how they share the first two parameters.

Now suppose I have some process which returns an `A`. In one case I would use `A` directly and in the other case I would like to use the `A` to make a `B`(after providing the third param).

I could accomplish this with the following method:

```
scala> def mkBFromA(a: A, v3: Double): B = B(a.v1, a.v2, v3)
mkBFromA: (a: A, v3: Double)B

scala> mkBFromA(A(1, "t"), 3.14)
res0: B = B(1,t,3.14)
```

However I don't like how I have to copy all of the parameters over.

Is there a better way to do this?

I am using case classes because this will be used to make an Apache Spark `DataFrame` (which likes case classes)

Comment: If you don't need to construct a `B` directly, you can just make it `case class B(a: A, v3: Double)`. Otherwise you can certainly write a macro to do this.

Comment: @evan058 if you reading the data from a file or some storage source like HDFS or S3 , you can create a struct type variable and use that to define `dataframe`.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov is there a clean way to flatten your `B` when I used `toDF`? Your suggestion yields a DF with the schema: `[a: struct<v1:int,v2:string>, v3: double]`

Comment: @RajatMishra that would certainly work. What I am actually doing is transforming text into a series case classes representing ngrams features. I am trying to use the same method to generate the standard features to the training and test sets, meaning that I have `TrainingFeatures` and `TestFeatures` where `TestFeatures` is a subset of `TrainingFeatures` (training has the target "truth" column)

Answer (score 3):

Since the intended use case is Spark SQL and  `DataFrame` it shouldn't require any special approach. You can convert from `A` to `B` by adding a column:

```
Seq(A(1, "foo")).toDS.withColumn("v3", lit(1.0)).as[B]
```

and from `B` to `A` with `as` alone:

```
Seq(B(2, "bar", 2.0)).toDS.as[A]
```

Comment: Hmm, the value of `v3` is computed using the contents of the `A` instance but I suppose I could use a UDF to accomplish this